# Аргументы стрелочной функции

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Доброго времени суток.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, смысл записи аргументов:

```
 const eventHandler => argument => event { 
           //   some function
        }
```

Comment: а где вы такое увидели ?

Comment: Ещё не разу не видел такой интерпретации толи контактны, толи функции стрелки...

Comment: как по мне так тут как минимум 2ве си нтаксических ошибки, я хз че ето такое :)

Answer (score 3):

Здесь есть функция, которая принимает аргументом eventHandler и возвращает функцию, которая принимает аргументом argument и возвращает функцию, которая принимает аргументом event. Например:

```
const f = eventHandler => argument => event => {
    return eventHandler + argument + event;
};

global.console.log(f(1)(20)(300));
```

На выходе будет 321

Comment: это карирование в es6 синтаксисе?

Comment: @torokhkun лучше не скажешь

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, понял. Это как:

```
const evenHandler = function(argument) {    
    return function(event) {
        // some function
    }
}
```

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/198782)

Comment: @slippyk это не дополнение к вопросу, это ответ, вполне себе исчерпывающий.